# How to create the subpaths that exactly match to the users’ name

Tags: python, google-app-engine

After I direct the users to their pages, like `/example/john`, how do I make the `webapp.RequestHandler` to handle the this page? If I do this `('/user.*', UsersSubPath)` that matches the all pages after `/user/`, If I do `('/user/user.name*', UsersSubPath)`, that’s not working either since it can’t substitute the `user.name` by the user’s name automatically. 
Btw, `self.redirect('something')`, returns an URL string or nothing?

Thank you.

Comment: Check out URL Mappings: The regular expression can contain regexp groupings to match parts of the URL. Patterns matched in groupings are passed to request handlers as arguments. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture that part of the URL using a regular expression, and then pass that captured text to your handler method as an argument, something like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util


class ExampleHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, name="default"):
        self.response.out.write('Hello %s!' % name)


def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/example/(\w+)', MainHandler)],
                                         debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
```

...in the list of handlers, the bit `(\w+)` tells the system to match one or more 'word' characters, and capture them together into a group. That group of characters will be passed into the `get()` method of the `ExampleHandler` class.

Comment: doesn't ('/example/*/') will work to, where any "*" represents a value passed into the get() method? like ('/example/*/*/*/') with get(self, arg1, arg2, arg3)?

Comment: Almost -- you'd need `/example/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)` (parens to capture, `.*` or `.+` to say what to capture) -- the link @Calvin posted above has fuller details.